# に as the subject marker?

Tags: particles, particle-に, particle-が

In an anime I was watching the other day, I heard the bellow phrase. I don't remember whose name it was or which anime it was, so I'll just replace it with a generic name:

> アリスに分かってる.

The speaker was Alice, and it was translated as "Alice knows [about it]". I find this odd. Wouldn't the に particle refer to the thing that the person is "understanding" or "knowing" in that instance? I am confused why it's not

> [私が]それにわかってる

Comment: [istrasci's answer](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/4442/542) might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

分かる is a potential verb, and therefore takes に.

- [Use of に in 「私には本物の若殿様がわかります」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24955/5010)
- [How to denote the object and the subject of potential form verbs clearly?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/40586/5010)
- [Why say "〜、皆には出来る。" instead of " 〜、皆は出来る。" in this context?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36481/5010)

Note that this sentence would be much more natural if there is a topic marker, は:

> アリスには(それが)分かっている。 Alice knows (it).

In case you don't know why ～ている is used, check [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/38773/5010).

Comment: I'm a bit confused, wouldn't the potential be 分かられる？

Comment: @DelectableTea good question. See: [this related QA](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5988/why-doesnt-%E5%88%86%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8B-have-a-potential-form)

Comment: Ah so it technically already is a potential of "to divide [split into parts]". I guess "to be able to divide" could just mean "understand" as it relates to knowledge, i.e. the ability to 'divide' the knowledge from non-discerned or non-discerned knowledge. In other words, the ability to discern what is true and false, i.e. be able to divide truth and falsehood, is the same as 'understanding'.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, I thought　わかる used が　「日本語がわかる」, is it because に is marking the indirect object? like [（僕には）日本語がわかる」, same for [僕の友達に何をしている？」?

Comment: Feel free to correct me experts: Isn't "Japanese" the object in the English sentence "I [can] understand Japanese". Let me take out は so we can focus on the に - 僕に日本語が分かる - Even though Naruto mentioned that this is less natural, one can still illustrate the point. Potential verbs describe a "state of feasibility" ([Tae Kim](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/potential)) and the に is marking who "has" that state, or to put it in Kim's terms the "target" of the state of feasibility.

Comment: So if the に is marking the "subject" who "understands" then が has to mark something else. In english terms, the "object".