# Dative subject constructions with 「もらえませんか」

Tags: particle-に, giving-and-receiving, subjects, dative-subject-constructions

Back to basics. I have heard sentences similar to these ones online that attest the same structure

> 私も弾いてみたい、と思った私はすぐさま「私にも教えてもらえませんか。」と願い出ました。([source](http://www.tetsukuro.net/tetsukoma.php))

> あとで時間があったら、その秘訣を私にも教えてもらえませんか。([source](https://wikiwiki.jp/azphel/%E3%82%B2%E3%83%AB%E3%82%AF%E3%83%9E%E3%83%AB%E3%82%B9%E8%A6%81%E5%A1%9E2))

> アーモンドさん（左）「私に貸してもらえませんか？」([source](https://ameblo.jp/snakewood/entry-12557438011.html))

> 是非とも夢ある皆さんの力を私に貸してもらえませんか？([source](https://www.a-i-s.co.jp/files/news43.html))

Why に? In all of these sentences isn't the subject 「私」? The agent of the action is the other party, and 「もらう」determines the subject is the benefector of the action. What am I missing here? There seems to be a function fusion of indirect object with subject of sentence.

Comment: Isn't it just that the 私 in each example is the indirect object of 教える or 貸す?

Comment: @Leebo I guess so. I think that's why this construction didn't sound particularly out of place to me at first. But people also say things like 「先生に教えてもらいました」where にmarks the indirect object/patient. My issue with the examples, in other words, could be with the confusion that comes with the presence of both に and もらう. (Or maybe the function fusion of indirect object with subject of sentence?)

Comment: Related maybe? [が and に interchangeability and difference in meaning](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4440) and [に as the subject marker?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/40868)

Comment: Remember that に also marks the agent of the action:  think of its use with the causative.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments by Leebo, Eddie Kal, and A. Ellett, the に marks the agent of actions in certain constructions.  We sometimes use *by* in English in a similar fashion.

In the ～てもらう construction, consider that the agent of the verb もらう is *getting* (もらう) something *done* (the ～て verb) for them.  This is, in some ways, not far from the passive, where に is also used to mark the agent (the doer of the action) and は or が to mark the patient (the receiver of the action).

- Passive:

  - 私**[は]{●}**先生**[に]{●}**教え**[ら]{●}[れ]{●}[た]{●}**
- "Getting":

  - 私**[は]{●}**先生**[に]{●}**教え**[て]{●}[も]{●}[ら]{●}[っ]{●}[た]{●}**

We might express this in English as:

- Passive:

  - I **was** taught **by** the teacher
- "Getting":

  - I **got** taught **by** the teacher

*Note: In English, the two are so close that they are essentially fusing in modern colloquial usage.  The "getting" sense of "receiving" is thus often expressed in a slightly wordier fashion, to avoid ambiguity:*

- *"Getting" with explicit "receiving":*

  - *I **got** the teacher **to teach me***

The key point to remember for ～てもらう constructions is that they are similar to the passive, and the agent (doer) of the ～て verb generally takes に.

Comment: This really helps clear things up! Just so happens I am actually in the process of revising the question and trying to crystalize the grammar aspect that I was having trouble with. I'd be grateful if you could also address the things I am going to add to the question (in a bit).